# Add up all aminals?

Tags: probability, statistics

Animal farm 2/3 cats, 5.55% dogs, 1/6 birds, and 2 mice. How many animals were there? The answer is 18? I converted fractions to decimals and added them all up but didn't get the right answer. Please help?

Comment: Are there animals other than cats, dogs, birds and mice?

Comment: I would imagine that $5.55\%$ is incorrect and what is intended is instead $5.\overline{5}\%=\frac{1}{18}$.  Add $\frac{2}{3}+5.\overline{5}\%+\frac{1}{6}$ to get $\frac{8}{9}$ total, meaning $\frac{8}{9}$ of the animals on the farm are cats, dogs, or birds.  Assuming no other animals are present, that leaves $\frac{1}{9}$ of the animals are mice.  Given that there are two mice, that implies that there are $2\cdot 9=18$ total animals.  Checking that the numbers work out for the other animals then confirms, $12$ cats, $1$ dog, $3$ birds and $2$ mice.

Comment: @JMoravitz Very smart mice, if they survive 12 cats.

Comment: Alternatively: There are clearly five animals on the farm, three of which are in such poor conditions which mean the farmer should be facing *animal cruelty* charges.  $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\frac{1}{18}=0.0555...$ This means the number of animals will be 18 or a multiple of 18.

So $\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{16}{18}$ and with 2 mice, you have the total amount of animals is 18. (If the fractions had added up to $\frac{17}{18}$, then the answer would have been 36.)

Answer (score 0):

5.55% = $\frac{1}{18}$ (well, not exactly, but that's most likely what they meant by the5.55%)

So, the cats, dogs, and birds make up $\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{16}{18}$ of all animals, so assuming there are no other aniamls than these and the two mice, then we know that the 2 mice make up $\frac{2}{18}$ of all animals, which is only true if the total number of animals is 18.